# Cassandra - Select returning null values depending WHERE clause

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cql

We have the following statement:

```
SELECT id, creationuser, lastversion FROM fenix
WHERE id = 96809ff7-313d-4c02-b9af-6ac38ae3df58 and lastversion = true LIMIT 1;
```

And the following result:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------+
id                                   | creationuser | lastversion |
------------------------------------------------------------------+
96809ff7-313d-4c02-b9af-6ac38ae3df58 | <<null>>     | true        |
------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Notice that the `creationuser` column has not been populated.

But, when we execute the following statement (with `where` clausure modified):

```
SELECT id, creationuser, lastversion FROM fenix
WHERE Id = 96809ff7-313d-4c02-b9af-6ac38ae3df58 limit 1;
```

We get a different result:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------+
id                                   | creationuser | lastversion |
------------------------------------------------------------------+
96809ff7-313d-4c02-b9af-6ac38ae3df58 | user_fenix1  | true        |
------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Why do we get different results when we change `WHERE` clause? Why returns a `<<null>>` value to an existing value?

**[EDIT]**

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE fenix (
      id                uuid,
      creationuser      text,
      lastversion       bool,
      creationdate      timestamp,
      editiondate       timestamp,
      PRIMARY KEY (id, creationdate, editiondate)
)WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY(creationdate DESC, editiondate DESC);
```

Full data on table:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
id                                   | creationuser | lastversion | creationdate               | editiondate              |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
96809ff7-313d-4c02-b9af-6ac38ae3df58 | user_fenix1  | true        | 2018-08-31 04:50:13+0000   | 2018-08-31 04:50:13+0000 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
96809ff7-313d-4c02-b9af-6ac38ae3df58 | user_fenix1  | false       | 2018-08-31 04:50:13+0000   | 2018-08-31 04:50:13+0000 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

CREATE SEARCH INDEX ON fenix WITH lastversion;
```

Comment: Could you also share your table structure?

Comment: Are there multiple rows for given 'id and latestversion' combination

Comment: Check Output with higher Consistency

Comment: @Horia
I updated the question with this information :)

Comment: @SouravGulati I updated the question with table data.

Comment: What version of cassandra and what are you using to make the queries? Looks kinda like a bug

Comment: You issue seems to similar to this :http://datanerds.io/post/cassandra-no-row-consistency/
Did you run any update? I would suggest a nodetool repair

Comment: @ChrisLohfink I'am using [cqlsh 5.0.1 | DSE 6.0.2 | CQL spec 3.4.5 | DSE protocol v2].

Comment: @SouravGulati Yes, I did a UPSERT to generate one of the lines for this example, why?

Comment: Can you try running same upsert again and then check?

Comment: `SELECT id, creationuser, lastversion FROM fenix
WHERE id = 96809ff7-313d-4c02-b9af-6ac38ae3df58 and lastversion = true LIMIT 1;` is not a legal request for the schema you provided without `ALLOW FILTERING`. Are you trying to use CAS? Having a "lastversion" wont really work without some kind of distributed coordination like using paxos.

Comment: @ChrisLohfink I updated the question, we have an search index.